# Tag synonyms: timestamps

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

Should [timestamp](/questions/tagged/timestamp), [timestamps](/questions/tagged/timestamps), and [unix-timestamp](/questions/tagged/unix-timestamp) be merged?

Comment: To be Meta-Meta: since there is such a big number of "should we merge tag a with tag b"-questions that *should* be solved by creating and voting on synonyms, is it possible that the synonym-mechanism needs an overhaul? At least the creation and voting on synonyms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd only merge [timestamps](/questions/tagged/timestamps) into [timestamp](/questions/tagged/timestamp).

I wouldn't merge [unix-timestamp](/questions/tagged/unix-timestamp) into this mix, because it describes a specialized version of a timestamp, seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 represented as 32/64-Bit Integer.